# Dropdown doesn't work after moving to another page Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a problem: on page load I have a dropdown menu with language select and it works fine until i move to another page of the site http://en.bls.com.ua/ (works on less then 1920px vw). It should appear on click (in top-right corner)

my php/html for this block

```
<div class="lang-block link-h-darked">
    @foreach($languages as $lang)
        @if($lang===$locale)
            @continue
        @endif

        @if(empty($controllerVariables['langs']))
            <a href="{{ route_locale($lang) }}" class="btn btn-lang">{{strtoupper($lang)}}</a>
        @elseif(!isset($controllerVariables['langs'][$lang]))
            <a href="{{ route_locale($lang, true) }}" class="btn btn-lang">{{strtoupper($lang)}}</a>
        @else
            <a href="{{ route_locale_with_slug($lang, Request::route()->getName(), $controllerVariables['langs'][$lang]) }}" class="btn btn-lang">{{strtoupper($lang)}}</a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="lang-block-dropdown d-md-flex align-items-center d-xl-none d-xs-none link-h-darked">
    @php
        if ($locale!==$languages[0]) {
            $first_lang = $languages[0];
        } else {
            $first_lang = $languages[1];
        }
    @endphp

    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn title-gray">{{ strtoupper(\App::getLocale()) }}</a>

    <div class="lang-select">
        @foreach($languages as $lang)
            @if($lang===$locale)
                @continue
            @endif

            @if(empty($controllerVariables['langs']))
                <a href="{{ route_locale($lang) }}" class="btn btn-lang">{{strtoupper($lang)}}</a>
            @elseif(!isset($controllerVariables['langs'][$lang]))
                <a href="{{ route_locale($lang, true) }}" class="btn btn-lang">{{strtoupper($lang)}}</a>
            @else
                <a href="{{ route_locale_with_slug($lang, Request::route()->getName(), $controllerVariables['langs'][$lang]) }}" class="btn btn-lang">{{strtoupper($lang)}}</a>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript for the appearance of dropdown

```
$('.lang-block-dropdown a').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass('active');
    $('.lang-select').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: did you try to make a page change like site http://en.bls.com.ua/ ?

Comment: the thing is that i totally need it to be dropdown

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that it's an SPA so it doesn't reload the page but rerender it through AJAX. So using JQuery delegates helped to solve the problem. The code below runs

```
 $('body').delegate('.lang-block-dropdown', 'click', function () {
    $(this.parentNode).toggleClass('active');
    $('.lang-select').toggleClass('.active-dropdown');
    $('.lang-select').slideToggle();
})
```